# Is Gravity Storage a pipe dream?

Tags: energy, gravity, renewable-energy, energy-storage

**Background**

Energy Vault has a new Gravity Storage system its spruiking ([Link here](https://www.energyvault.com/evx)). They are getting a lot of attention and funding. However I am skeptical on the technology and I don't understand why large companies are investing big (150-200m) into a dud idea.

**Gravity Storage Maths**

My math is probably wrong, but from my understanding

1. Potential energy is calculated as ***E[J] = mgh***.
2. Gravity is 9.81 m/s
3. The quoted height of the Gravity Vault EVx is 140m
4. They claim the technology is scalable to Multi GWhs. (lets say 1 GWh)
5. They claim a 85% round trip efficiency

So to get 1 GWh worth of storage, they would need 3.1 million tonnes of Mass.

1. 1 GWh = 3,600 GJ
2. 3,600 GJ = 3.1 million tonnes * 9.81 m/s * 140 m * 85% efficiency

**Viability?**

For reference, the Pyramid of Giza is estimated to weight 5.75 million tonnes.
So this EVx concept is essentially to build a massive cubic gantry system to lift and drop weights equivalent in mass to 54% of the Great Pyramid.

To me this just seems ludicrous and absurd, Even if you ignore the cost of sourcing 3.1 million tonnes of mass, you still need to build a huge cubic gantry out of steel, which needs to be assembled to precise margins to ensure winches and cranes operate smoothly. The footprint (and construction cost) of such a structure would be enormous.

**Help Requested**

Is the technology Viable, or is it a pipe dream?

Am I fundamentally missing something in my calculations?

Reason I ask, is I suspect there must be something to it, otherwise why would companies (BHP, Sun Metals, Atlas Renewables, China Tianying, etc) be willing to invest.

Comment: IDK, but we're getting near to the point where it will make no sense to build additional grid-scale, wind or solar generating capability if it is not backed up by some kind of storage. People don't only demand power when the wind blows or when the Sun shines. I predict that _any_ new proposal for energy storage is going to generate a lot of excitement until we find and settle on one that really works.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about company motivations and not about physics.

Comment: As Solomon said above, people need power when the wind isn't blowing or the sun isn't shining.  For example my industry is building hydrogen production units to take wind energy and turn it into hydrogen for power storage.  I would  like to look at the economics of this proposal. It seems that pumping water back upstream from Niagara Falls and controlling the flow by a dam would be a cheaper idea, but what ever works.

Comment: @Foolishmuse Hydrogen losses are super high. it takes 60 KWh to produce 1 kg of hydrogen, which only contains 30 KWh of potential energy. When you put that through a Hydrogen Fuel Cell, you lose 50% and only get out 15 KWh into the grid.  thats a 25% efficiency factor, compared with 95% for Chemical Batteries & 70% for pumped hydro.

Comment: @BowlOfRed, the question is if the technology is viable. On the exchange, dozens of people ask similar questions, such as if Nuclear Fusion is Viable, if Space Elevators are viable?, etc. This question is along the same lines, why would you vote to close?

Comment: I don’t know anything about this ‘technology’, but from the link “_Gravity storage refers to the use of energy to place objects at height that are then lowered under natural “gravitational” force to create physical movements which turn mechanical motors and create electricity_”. The first thing that comes to mind is that the amount of energy generated by this lowering will be $\le$ the energy required to get the objects where they initially were, and so I can’t see how it’d be viable. But I have not looked into this at all.

Comment: @BobbyHeyer, if the only question in them "is it viable", I would VTC those as well.   If the question is more directed about a particular physics aspect or a particular challenge, I think it belongs here.  There's a lot of physics statements and equations in your post, but there's no questions about any of them. The entire question seems to be "I don't know why x is investing in this can you tell me?", and that doesn't seem like a physics question to me.

Comment: Water storage is gravity storage, and it is done.

Comment: @BobbyHeyer, 25% is better than 0%, which is what you get if you have no capacity for storage at all. And, 25% would be better than 50% (or more!) if the life-time cost of the system that returns 25% of the "saved" energy happens to be substantially less than the cost of the more efficient system.  (Note: I'm not claiming to know anything about the life-time costs of hydrogen storage, or pumped hydro, or batteries or any other such scheme.)

Comment: @foolishmuse, Talk about carrying coals to Newcastle! Pumping water back up from Lake Ontario to Lake Erie will make sense _if and when_ they have to completely shut off the falls in order to meet the demand for electricity.

Comment: @BobbyHeyer  yes converting electricity to  hydrogen  and back again is inefficient. I'm in that industry so I am well aware that 30% is about the best you can get.  Only suitable for some remote locations where nothing else is practical.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is much more an energy business question than a physics question. The answer is likely cost effectiveness - chemical batteries are expensive, pumped hydro requires having available mountains and water. Sourcing a lot of mass is easy (since it can be anything, and concrete for containers has a good infrastructure), and the engineering of gantries is a standard area of engineering.

If a bunch of different, competing companies are interested in an idea and actually paying for testing it out, it is actually a strong signal that there is something to it. Economically, they are at the very least finding the value of investigating (dollars of expected discounted revenue if it works times probability that it works) larger than the amount of invested money. The value of information about the probability of success is proportional to the value invested: if there was an obvious physics showstopper anybody with an engineering background could show to the board in an hour it would already have been presented. So while I am sure there are many challenges here, I would be surprised if there was something physically wrong here.